# How to call a function from Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract?

Tags: magento-1.9, core

I'm trying to call a function from `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` core model in a observer. How can I do?

Comment: Try describing what you want to achieve instead of how you want it. Maybe there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

There are no static methods in that class and you cannot instantiate it either, because it's abstract.
But if you need to call a method from that class, either your approach is wrong or you already have an instance of a class that extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` and you can call that method from the instance you have available.

Comment: In a Controller ------- I have a variable $result (used for `Mage::dispatchEvent('payment_method_is_active', array('result'=> $checkResult, 'method_instance' => $method, 'quote' => $quote,));`). In a Observer ---------- I had a function that use `$result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();`. How can I set up the controller variable to work in observer?

Comment: I've tried like this : ` $checkResult = new StdClass; $checkResult->isAvailable = true`. But when I'm trying to  make ` $result->isAvailable = false` from observer, It didn't hide me the result(one payment method).

Comment: If I just make somethng that use that observer method it works.(for xample change payment method)